# Regular Expressions, detecting a text pattern

Tags: php, regex

I'm interacting with my users via SMS, if they send me an SMS with this pattern, I need to perform an action:

Pattern:

```
*TEXT*TEXT*TEXT#
```

In `TEXT` all the characters are allowed, so I have made this regex:

```
if (preg_match('/^\*([^*]*)\*([^*]*)\*([^#]*)\#$/', $text)){
    // perform the action...
}
```

The above regex works actually good, but it's not allowing next `lines after` **#**, for example:

`'*hello there*how you doing!?* and blah#'` pass the regex, but:

```
'*hello there*how you doing!?* and blah#

'
```

is not passed by the above regex(pay attention to the next lines after **#**)

So I decided to:

```
$text = str_replace("\n\r", '', $text);
```

But the above example is still not passed :-(

How should I allow next lines here in the regex? or get rid of them?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Since you're storing the information matched with the regex, remove `$` from the pattern.

Comment: @BackinaFlash But this ruins the whole thing, if they type *#test#* after the latest `#` this still passes the regex...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To allow for optional spaces and/or newlines after the hash:

```
if (preg_match('/^\*([^*]*)\*([^*]*)\*([^#]*)\#\s*$/', $text)){
```

I've added `\s*` as the expression just before the end-of-subject.

You can also use trim beforehand:

```
if (preg_match('/^\*([^*]*)\*([^*]*)\*([^#]*)\#$/', trim($test))){
```

**Update**

As an added requirement that text between the stars cannot be empty:

```
if (preg_match('/^\*([^*]+)\*([^*]+)\*([^#]+)\#$/', trim($test))){
```

Comment: should be also `m` in the regex as @hamza suggested or not? thanks

Comment: also should I add `+` to forbid **(when it's empty)? would you please edit the answer, I'm not really good at regex... thanks

Comment: @behz4d Yeah, adding a `+` instead of `*` would help to prevent empty strings between the stars.

Comment: lol, my mistake sorry, i'm testing many regex i thought yours was not working, I just checked i'm using yours!

Answer (score 1):

Oops error, like @Jack said we must add \s* and forget about "m".

I changed `*` to `+` so that it returns false when there's nothing between `**` :

```
$text = "*fddsfdsf*dfdfd*5f8ssfdssf8#

";
if (preg_match('/^\*([^*]+)\*([^*]+)\*([^#]+)\#\s*$/', $text)){
    echo "yes";
}else{
  echo "no";
}
```

Comment: This also matches `"*fddsfdsf*dfdfd*5f8ssfdssf8#\nsomething else"`